# Multithreading Queue Operations Not Faster than Single Threaded

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I am designing a multithreaded routine in python where one function adds a function to a queue and several helper threads concurrentlt pop things off the queue until it's empty. In theory this should be much faster than a single threaded implementation but in both the real application and the toy example I designed for this question it's not the case. I'm guessing the reason is some synchronization issue with the Queue object (which is threadsafe according to python documentation) but that's only a guess. Any help with general optimizations is appreciated!

And the code for the toy example:

```
from Queue import Queue
import time
queue = Queue(maxsize=0)
counter = []

#called by an external main method, adds and removes from global queue in single thread
def single_thread():
    fillit()
    time_origin = "%.10f" % time.time()
    while not queue.empty():
        queue.get()
    time_end = "%.10f" % time.time()
    time_t = float(time_end) - float(time_origin)
    print "time of single threaded implementation: " + str(time_t) +"\n"

#called by an external main method; adds to queue and removes from queue in multiple threads
def multi_thread():
    fillit()
    time_origin = "%.10f" % time.time()
    spawn_threads(4)
    time_end = "%.10f" % time.time()
    time_t = float(time_end) - float(time_origin)
    print "time of multi threaded implementation: " + str(time_t) +"\n"

#Fills up the queue with 2^19 elements
def fillit():
    for i in range(2 ** 19):
        queue.put(i)

#Spawns n helper threads to help empty the queue
def spawn_threads(num_threads):
    for i in range(num_threads):
        counter.append(0)
        thread = myThread(i, "Thread-" + str(i))
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()
    while not queue.empty():
        continue
    print "done with threads " + str(counter) +" elements removed!"

#THREADING SUPPORT CODE
import threading

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
    def run(self): #each thread continues to empty the queue while it still has elements
        while not queue.empty():
            queue.get()
            global counter
            counter[self.threadID] +=1
```

Results below:

```
time of single threaded implementation: 1.51300001144

done with threads [131077, 131070, 131071, 131070] elements removed!
time of multi threaded implementation: 7.77100014687
```

Comment: Why are you casting the start and end time to strings, just to cast them back to floats to calculate the time elapsed?

Comment: @BrendanAbel What you say is valid for casting in the start times. That's certainly not related to the slowdown I'm experiencing though.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing here is the python GIL in action. The GIL ensures only 1 thread per process executing python code, which makes multithreading tasks that are not IO-bound slower, instead of faster, see [this link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). If you want to do real concurrency, take a look at multiprocessing instead of multithreading. Be aware though that multiprocessing has more overhead, because of the lack of shared state and spinning up processes is more costly.

Comment: Pycharm (the ide I'm using) compiles with the --multiproc flag. Does this affect threading across multiple processes or is the GIL still a limiting factor? What module/platform would you suggest for getting the behavior I want?

Comment: Python is just not capable of true multithreading, so there is no platform on which you will get the desired behavior